# Sass::SyntaxError in Static_pages#home - Invalid CSS After "": error when trying to add code to a CSS file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Anytime I add code to my CSS file I get this error when working with Bootstrap.

```
    Invalid CSS after "": expected selector or at-rule, was "<!DOCTYPE html>" (in /users/app_project/app/assests/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)

    Extracted source (around line #4):

    1: <!DOCTYPE html>
    2: <html>
    3:     <head>
    4:      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    5:      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    6:      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    7:     </head>
```

I was previously able to add code to it without any error but at some point I must have made a change somewhere that has created this problem.

Here is the original CSS I was working with that caused no errors

```
     @import "bootstrap";

     /*universal*/

     html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
     }

    body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    }

    section {
    overflow: auto;
    }

    textarea {
    resize: vertical;
    }

    .center {
    text-align: center;
    }

    .center h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .container-fluid {
    background-color: #eee;
    }

    /* typography */

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    line-height: 1;
    }

    h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    h2 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: black;
    }

    p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    }

    #logo {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #d81010;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    }

    #logo:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    li {
    text-align: left;
    }

    h1#class {
    color:#ff5a28;
    }

    .nav-center {
    color: blue;
    }
```

Here is some code I tried to add that caused an error.

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    }

    html, bodY {
    height: 100%;
    }

    .wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
    }

    .footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
    }

    footer {
    background-color: #70ff00;
    }
```

It's not just the above code that causes an error. Any additional CSS causes me to get the error.

What am I doing wrong? I can post the html code I am working with as well if it is needed.

Comment: Apparently Sass is trying to compile your HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I don't quite understand what you mean. This is fairly new to me.

Comment: Sass is only for Sass/CSS.  It says you have some HTML in there somewhere, which has an invalid Sass syntax.

Comment: Okay, so there is some HTML in my CSS code?

Comment: What command, exactly are you using to compile?

Comment: I am just checking my work locally, like http://localhost:3000/. Sorry if this isn't what you mean by compiling. I update the code in my editor, then check it by going to localhost:3000

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while using Middleman.
It seems that the build process was trying to apply a particular layout to all files in the source folder. A little search got me to infer that the layout was being applied even to complete HTML test files present in bower components. As a result there were  tags from the test files nested within  tags from my layout.
I solved the problem by specifying a regex in config.rb that the layout be applied to only specific HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code. You have

```
html, bodY {
height: 100%;
}
```

in sass file. Convert this code to

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
```

You have wrong body tag for css. This is causing error.